# How to check if unix account has been created with "--disabled-login" and "---disabled-password"

Tags: linux, security, login, account-restrictions

In Linux distributions like RedHat you can create a user with options `--disabled-login` and `---disabled-password` (see man page for command `adduser` [link](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/adduser/adduser.8.en.html)).

I wonder if it is possible to check for an administrator after user creation if the login and password is disabled for a given user? Exists there any possibility?

Comment: Have a look at `/etc/shadow/`. The second field is the password. When it starts with  double exclamation mark `!!`, the account is locked. Run `adduser` with different options and explore the effect on the new user's line in the shadow file.

Comment: in almost every case, saying something like "in Unix...", is a generalization, one that doesn't apply. E.g. FreeBSD and OpenBSD do have `adduser`, but it's not the same command as on Linuxen, and doesn't have those flags. Also, on Debian, `adduser` is a Perl script that calls `useradd`, on FreeBSD it's described as a shell script that uses the `pw` command. Actually, it's not even the same command across different Linuxes, as in CentOS, it appears to be a link to `useradd`...

Comment: Thank you for your comments, i have precised the query and refering to common  linux distributions in the enterprise like RedHat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information can be gathererd using the `passwd` utility.

From `man passwd`

> **-S, --status**
>
> Display account status information. The status information consists of 7 fields. The first field is the user's login name. The second field indicates if the user account has a locked password
> (L), has no password (NP), or has a usable password (P). The third field gives the date of the last password change. The next four fields are the minimum age, maximum age, warning period, and
> inactivity period for the password. These ages are expressed in days.

To check the status of every user on the system, run

```
passwd -a -S
```

A disabled (locked) user might look like this:

```
apache L 08/30/2019 0 99999 7 -1
```

Note the `L`, indicating the account is locked.

A regular user might look like this:

```
panki P 09/23/2019 0 99999 7 -1
```