# How to verify whether a user has a home directory or password?

Tags: bash, users, useradd

Where can I find details on how a user was created. And what is the current status of a user.

For example, `adduser` command can be run with `--no-create-home`, `--disabled-password`, `--home DIR` etc.

Is there any command which tells if a user has home directory or not. If it has home directory then what is the location of the directory.

Or if a user has password or not.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636503/how-to-check-if-unix-account-has-been-created-with-disabled-login-and-di/636508#636508. Home dir can be found in `/etc/passwd`

Comment: Use `getent passwd the_user` Read `man -a passwd` and `man getent`.

Comment: note that some systems (e.g. the Debian I looked at) have the home directory set to something like `/nonexistent` for system users that don't need it, so you may want to check if the named directory actually exists too, not just if the field is nonempty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`man 5 passwd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) for the format of password entries. Each user has a number of fields, separated by colons. The home directory is the sixth field, so

```
getent passwd user | cut -d: -f6
```

will show `user`’s home directory. That doesn’t imply that the directory exists; you need to check that separately.

```
homedir="$(getent passwd user | cut -d: -f6)"; [ -d "$homedir" ] && printf "User %s's home directory is %s and exists.\n" user "$homedir"
```

The password is the second field. It will usually be `x`, meaning that the password hash is in `/etc/shadow`, or `*`, meaning that password access is disabled for that account (`*` can also be found in `/etc/shadow`). You should really use `passwd` to determine whether an account is disabled; see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/636508/86440) for details.

```
[ "$(passwd -S user | cut -d\  -f2)" = P ] && printf "User %s has a password.\n" user
```